# Restrict PHP-CLI for a user

Tags: php

I'd like to restrict using PHP-CLI for a user. I mean on the same server, I want to use PHP-CLI with my account and I want no other user to access PHP-CLI interface. Or choose which user can use it.

Is this possible?

Comment: Now everything is possible. You could use some kind of jailshell or something to block access to binaries you want.

Comment: Generally root/system administrator can do everything. So the answer strictly is no. (Except if "the" user is the root...)

Comment: Yes, I meant except the root.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many ways. A simple one:

```
chmod 754 /usr/bin/php
chgrp php /usr/bin/php
```

Then add only the person you want to that php group

Of course, apache or the web user should also be in that group too.

Comment: So the user who is in the "php" group can execude commands and no other user can, right?

Comment: Yes. And of course root user can do anything. That won't change.

Comment: Thank you. This is good for my Ubuntu server. Is there anyway to disable CLI on cpanel?

Comment: cpanel runs with apache user. You probably will need to do some serious hacks to get there.